# AmCharts maps - how to get only 2 first letters of country name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, maps, angular5, amcharts

I am stuck with a problem in Amcharts maps. A have a map with countries And the names is written like United States - but I need just US. Maybe some country formatter.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can use this rest api to get freely all the correspondent data for each country: https://restcountries.eu. I believe that this service may fit your need:   https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/{name}.

Comment: Which version of amCharts are you using, v3 or v4? In v4, the IDs of countries use their ISO2 code, so you'd get 2-letter stuff out of the box. But it's not the first 2 letters of the country's name, though...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for answers. I fixed it. I just get map id from AmCharts, and everything became alright.